# looping over error messages to diplay on page. some are success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to diplay error messages on the Page, but i amstuck

trying this code

```
$("div.msg").html(isAnswer[1]).addClass('warning');
```

now the `isAnswer[1]` is returning me the string as: `Updated^1,Failed^-1,CompleteSession^1`

So a success entry contains `1` at the end separated by `^` sign and failed entry contains `-1` at the end separated by `^` sign

now i want to show it like this that i loop over this `isAnswer[1]` array and separate them by adding a success to `1` and error class to `-1` and do the show the `^1` or `^-1` in message

Comment: Is this what you are looking for - http://plnkr.co/edit/RAsjUZuiGKTFtjLBkpfl?p=preview

Comment: does not load, please check

Comment: It is getting loaded perfectly for me. Well posting an answer for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script

```
var str = "Updated^1,Failed^-1,CompleteSession^1"; // your string
var strArray = str.split(","); // split the string with , - returns array
for (var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) { // iterating over array
    var obj = strArray[i]; // get the first object e.g. Updated^1
    var objArray = obj.split("^"); // Further split with ^
    var span = $("<span></span>"); // Create span
    span.html(objArray[0]); // Add text to span e.g. Updated

    if (objArray[1] == "1") { // Check whether it is success or failure and add class accordingly
        span.addClass("success");
    } else {
        span.addClass("error");
    }
    $("div.msg").append(span); // Append the span to div

}
```

CSS

```
.success {
    color: green;
}

.error {
    color: red;
}

div.msg span {
    margin - right: 5 px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="msg"></div>
```

Plunker for your reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/RAsjUZuiGKTFtjLBkpfl?p=preview

**Update based on comment**

In case you want to add custom text, replace the following code

```
span.html(objArray[0]); // Add text to span e.g. Updated

if (objArray[1] == "1") { // Check whether it is success or failure and add class accordingly
    span.addClass("success");
} else {
    span.addClass("error");
}
```

to

```
if (objArray[1] == "1") { // Check whether it is success or failure and add class accordingly
    span.html(objArray[0] + "Success");
    span.addClass("success");
} else {
    span.html(objArray[0] + "Failure");
    span.addClass("error");
}
```

Comment: how to add custom text different for update and error

Comment: Rather than adding text to span before if/else - move the code to if/else block and then add different custom text.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.msg").html(
  isAnswer[1].split(',')[0]
             .split('^')[1]
).addClass(
  isAnswer[1].split(',')[0]
             .split('^')[1] =='1' ? 'success':'warning'
);
```

Comment: can i add a custom text too with respect to success and warning too

Comment: yup just concat string

Comment: can u update ur answer with some custom text ike i asked, i am not in javascript,